# Get children resources URIs with the Hateoas library for PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, doctrine-orm, hateoas

Here is a `User` entity I want to `GET` with the [Hateoas](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas) library:

```
/**
 * [...]
 *
 * @Hateoas\Relation(
 *  "self",
 *  href=@Hateoas\Route("api_get_user", parameters={"id"="expr(object.getId())"})
 * )
 * @Hateoas\Relation(
 *  "placeofbirth",
 *  href="expr(link(object.getPlaceOfBirth(), 'self'))",
 *  exclusion=@Hateoas\Exclusion(excludeIf="expr(object.getPlaceOfBirth() === null)")
 * )
 */
class User
{
    // [...]

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Place")
     * @Serializer\Exclude
     */
    private $placeOfBirth;

    // [...]
}
```

My REST Response is correct. The `_links` part expectedly contains a URI for my `OneToOne` relation:

```
{
  // [...]
  "_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "\/api\/v0.1\/users\/1"
    },
    "placeofbirth": {
        "href":"\/api\/v0.1\/places\/3"
    }
  }
}
```

However, I don't know how to get the same with a `OneToMany` relation. For example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Place", mappedBy="visitor")
 * @Serializer\Exclude
 */
private $visitedPlaces;
```

I would like to get (something like):

```
{
  // [...]
  "_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "\/api\/v0.1\/users\/1"
    },
    "visitedPlaces": [
        { "href": "\/api\/v0.1\/place\/1" },
        { "href": "\/api\/v0.1\/place\/2" },
        { "href": "\/api\/v0.1\/place\/3" },
        { "href": "\/api\/v0.1\/place\/4" }
    ]
  }
}
```

I know I can get the `visitedPlaces` as [embedded resources](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas#embedding-resources), and it works, but this is not what I want. I don't want to get the whole object, only the resource URI, just as I do with a single-resource relation (see place of birth).

Is it possible, and if so how?